# Chrome - "Out of memory" on single tab & crash of DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, crash, google-chrome-devtools, out-of-memory, devtools

We're developing a web application that uses vue.js (Vue 2). It renders SVGs and communicates via WebSockets with a C# backend/web server that periodically sends messages which update the state of various SVGs objects (color, position etc.).

When running this web application in e.g. Chrome, the page crashes after a certain amount of time (depending on the performance of the machine the browser is running on, this time can vary).

The result is:

[Message in browser tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbT0r.png)

[Message in DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM762.png)

We've already tried different debugging approaches:

- Adding more console logging output to the web application
- Excluding certain parts of the web application to isolate the cause of the problem to a certain code part
- Chrome DevTools Memory profiling tools

Unfortunately, we could still not find the cause of this issue. Furthermore, as Chrome DevTools also crash, we cannot get a heap snapshot etc. just before the moment that crash occurs, as it cannot be predicted accurately. We were able to collect snapshots one or two minutes before the crash, but these snapshots didn't show us anything unusual.

Is there any other way we could localize the cause of this problem? Like external tools for profiling, setting specific debugging options in Chrome, debugging Chrome itself ...